# Can you see a worlds creator in the world file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was just wondering if there is a way to see the name of the player who created a world if you let's say use it for a public server or share it as an adventure map.

Answer (score 1):

The players that have opened the world are stored in the `playerdata` folder of the world. There is a file for each player named with the player UUID: e.g. `93b459be-ce4f-4700-b457-c1aa91b3b687.dat`. You can use a tool like https://mcuuid.net to convert that to a player name.

If you don't want your name to be assigned to a world just delete this file before distributing the save.

If you want to know who created a world you can use the above procedure but note that it is really easy to forge so it is not like a signature.

Comment: Is the playerdata sorted? Otherwise, how do you tell which of the guid is the creator, if multiple people have accessed the map?

Comment: @Polygnome It is not sorted but presumably, when you first extract the map only the creator(s) will have had the chance to open the world so far.

Comment: So this only works on a map that wasn't already in use, e.g. it won't work on a map of a public server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! You seem to know what you're talking about so I hope you can help me more: I am making a world that I will uplload for a server but I will change my username soon. Can I just delete the file without the tool? Since I am the only one who worked on this world?

Comment: @user258964 yes, just delete the file before you upload the world